# Typescript - Remove multiple char at the begin and end of a string/Get attributs of list JSON element

Tags: arrays, json, string, typescript, parsing

I have this following string :

```
"{"element":"634634"}"
```

I'd like to remove `{"element":"` which is always the same and the last char `"}`
the only thing which is dynamic (size can change) is `634634`
how can I do that ?

Or maybe someone can help with that :

I have this following array :

[image: Array of element]
I would like to make an Array of string (myArray: string[]) which contains "734734", "utruytuyt" , ... Is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is in JSON format, you can simply parse it.

```js
const str = '{"element":"634634"}';

const obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(obj.element);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate over the array using `Array.map()` to achieve an array of those strings:

```js
const listElement = [
  '{"element":"734734"}',
  '{"element":"utruytuyt"}',
  '{"element":"07078"}',
  '{"element":"khgkhg45"}',
];

const result = listElement.map((str: string) => JSON.parse(str).element);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use Javascript to work with that string.

For example you may to replace you symbol with empty using function

```
replace('}', '');
```